# Qt BLE For Android: Cannot read value of characteristic for Custom Service

Tags: android, qt, bluetooth

Here is the setup:

A coworker created a small firmware that changes the value of a custom characteristic within a custom service (non standard unique 128 bit UUID) about once every second. The device used to transmit uses a BLE (Bluetooth low power) implementation.

I needed to implement a small App (as a working example ONLY) to monitor said value. However I've run into a small problem. I've follwed the instructions here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-le-overview.html and I've manged to discover the service and "read it" (I get us UUID) by using this code:

```
void BLETest::on_stateChanged(QLowEnergyService::ServiceState state){
#ifdef DBUG
    logger->out("Service Monitor State: " + lowEnergyServiceStateToString(state),Logger::LC_ORANGE);
#endif

    if (state == QLowEnergyService::ServiceDiscovered){
        QString chars = "";
        QList<QLowEnergyCharacteristic> clist = monitoredService->characteristics();
        for (int i = 0; i < clist.size(); i++){
            chars = clist.at(i).uuid().toString() + " - " + clist.at(i).name() + ": " + QString(clist.at(i).value());
            chars = chars + ". Value size: " + QString::number(clist.at(i).value().size()) + "<br>";
        }
        if (chars.isEmpty()){
            chars = "No characteristics found";
        }
        logger->out(chars);
    }

}
```

Now this prints the UUID of the service but the size of the value byte array is zero. Using another (private App) we can actually see the value field for the characteristic in that service changing. Furthermore, even though there was a connection done to the service's object characteristicChanged singal, that signal is never triggered, which I imagine is because the characteristic value can't be read.

My question is: Is there anything wrong with the code that you can't think of? Or is it simply that is not possible to monitor custom services and characteristics with the current BLE implementation of Qt Bluetooth?

PD: I'm using Qt 5.7.1

Comment: may be you need to read the descriptors? is the gatt server writing data into characteristics or descriptors?

Comment: Characteristics. This is for sure because it is written as an XML definition in the code which explicitly says charcteristic. The characteristic has the modify and read properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must enable the chracteristic notification by write 0x01 to client characteristic configuration descriptor (CCCD).

```
foreach(QLowEnergyCharacteristic c, srv->characteristics()){
    QLowEnergyDescriptor d = c.descriptor(QBluetoothUuid::ClientCharacteristicConfiguration);
    if(!c.isValid()){
        continue;
    }
    if(c.properties() & QLowEnergyCharacteristic::Notify){ // enable notification
        srv->writeDescriptor(d, QByteArray::fromHex("0100"));
    }
    if(c.properties() & QLowEnergyCharacteristic::Indicate){ // enable indication
        srv->writeDescriptor(d, QByteArray::fromHex("0200"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've marked the answer as correct because it is essentialy what I did. HOwever the client was configured by a propietary environment that used XML to set the characteristic. I am now able to read the original value but I'm not notified of its changes. Even if I poll it the value remains the same. I've opened another question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651989/qt-ble-for-android-characteristic-update-does-not-trigger-characteristicchanged