# Qt BLE For Android: Characteristic update does not trigger characteristicChanged signal

Tags: android, qt, bluetooth

Here is the thing a device that we have transmits regular updates of a custom characteristic of a custom service. The service and characteristic in this device is defined via a XML file. This, of course, is referring to the Bluetooth BLE protocol.

What I'm trying to do is create a simple Qt Android App that connects to the device and monitors the update. I've gotten as far as discovering the service and connecting it signal to it. I've done that using this code:

```
void BLETest::on_stateChanged(QLowEnergyService::ServiceState state){

    Q_UNUSED(state);

    // Only printing data if all services are in correct state.
    for (qint32 i = 0; i < monitoredServices.size(); i++){
        if (monitoredServices.at(i)->state() != QLowEnergyService::ServiceDiscovered){
            logger->out("There are still services that have not been discoverd",Logger::LC_ORANGE);
            return;
        }
    }

    QString msg = "PRINTING SERVICE DATA<br>";

    for (qint32 i = 0; i < monitoredServices.size(); i++){

        QLowEnergyService *monitoredService = monitoredServices.at(i);
        QList<QLowEnergyCharacteristic> clist = monitoredService->characteristics();

        msg = msg + "SERVICE: " + monitoredService->serviceName() + ". UUID: " + monitoredService->serviceUuid().toString() + "<br>";

        // Checking if this is the service that need connection.
        if (monitoredService->serviceUuid() == QBluetoothUuid(QString("0a464eef-af72-43fd-8a8b-1f26f6319dab"))){
            QString res;
            if (connect(monitoredService,SIGNAL(characteristicChanged(QLowEnergyCharacteristic,QByteArray)),this,SLOT(on_charastericChanged(QLowEnergyCharacteristic,QByteArray)))) res = "true";
            else res = "false";
            logger->out("CONNECTED TO TARGET SERVICE: " + res,Logger::LC_ORANGE);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < clist.size(); i++){

            QString name = clist.at(i).name();
            if (name.isEmpty()) name = "UNDEFINED NAME";

            QByteArray buffer = clist.at(i).value();
            //QString value = QString(clist.at(i).value());
            QString value = QByteArray(buffer.toHex()) + " (BS = " + QString::number(buffer.size())  + ")";
            QString properties = QString::number(clist.at(i).properties());
            msg = msg + "CHARACTERISTIC: " + clist.at(i).uuid().toString() + " - " + name + ": " + value + ". PROPERTIES: " + properties  + "<br>";

        }

        if (clist.isEmpty()){
            msg = msg + "No characteristics found<br>";
        }
    }

    logger->out(msg);


}
```

The above functions waits for all services to be discovered then prints the UUID, name and Value for all characteristics of all services. When the service I want to monitored is processed a connection is done to the changedCharacteristic signal.

When I do this the printed value of the characteristic of the service I want to monitor is the original value for that characteristic. However as that value updates I'm not notified (the signal never triggers) and so the value never changes in my app.

Do I need to write some code to actually trigger the signals?

PD: Using the Blue Gecko Demo App I can see the values changing.

EDIT: I decided to use a timer to Poll the value of the characteristic and it never changes. Which might indicate why the signal is never generated either.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect a chracteristic changed handler to the service:

```
connect(service, SIGNAL(characteristicChanged(QLowEnergyCharacteristic, QByteArray)), this, SLOT(on_characteristicChanged(QLowEnergyCharacteristic, QByteArray)));
```

In the slot you can explore the data array.

However, the signal (characteristicChanged()) will only emitted by the service if the for this chracteristic notification is enabled. This works only, if the characteritic has a notify property, that should the case in your application.

Comment: The service send a notification to you if the characteristic is changed, so you dont need the timer to poll the characteristic.